# How to create a wireshark display filter with wildcard?

Tags: wireshark

Suppose I have a pattern like

```
01:02:(anything):04:05
```

How can I construct a display filter in wireshark to filter it out?

Must I do this?

```
data[0:2]==01:02 and data[3:2]==04:05
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure how many letter are in between the string you can use below filter

data.data ~ Hel.{1,}rld

or

data.data matches Hel.{1,}rld

here .{1,} means 1 or more characters in between & the letter should start from hel (in between anything) than ends with rld

Answer (score 5):

To use wildcard, you may use **.** (dot).

Both the searches below will give same result,

```
data.data ~ "Hello World"
data.data ~ He..o.Wor.d
```

In your case `01:02:(anything):04:05`, if we do not know length of `(anything)` this may not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `matches` operator.  This allows you to define regular expression matches.  Consider this:

`eth.dst matches "\xff.*\xff"`

This will look for ethernet destination addresses that have a 0xFF followed by something (or nothing) and another 0xFF within it.  So for your case, you could do:

`eth.addr matches "\x01\x02.*\x04\x05"`

This will look for those byte sequences in either the source or destination MACs.  You could refine it more by using a byte count if you wanted to.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `matches` operator doesn't work for the generic `data` though.  The wireshark-filter man page states that, *"[it is] only implemented for protocols and for protocol fields with a text string representation."*  

Keep in mind that the data is the undissected remaining data in a packet, and not the beginning of the Ethernet frame.  

Ref: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html

Comment: True.  Based on how the question was written I jumped to the conclusion that he was looking at ethernet addresses.